# Why is a global variable (inside function) not identified?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So, I was trying to initialize variables and put a few global variables in my Unity script, but when I run the code, it says that x, y, and z are unknown identifiers. I've been trying to find the answer to this:

```
function Awake () {
    x = 0; //Unity doesn't work with commas 
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetTouch) {
        x = x-1;
    }
    Transform.position = Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```

The thing with putting the variables outside the function is that they will repeat and act as update.

I'm also new to Unity, and JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure `Awake` is called before update?  Otherwise x, y, z won't be defined.

Comment: in your case...`x,y,z` are not global variables. These are local variables to the function `Awake`. If you want to make it global, take it to the outside of all functions.

Comment: @mestarted that is incorrect. When declaring + initializing a variable without the `var` keyword or `let` keyword for ES6+, the variable automatically becomes attached to the global namespace (`window` in browsers, `global` in node.js)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts as this is unity, I think there's a required explicit scoping. So you do need `var`

Comment: @winhowes if unity needed `var` then his script would have thrown a syntax error instead of running the way he described. Based on the description, it sounded like @BrendanAbel was correct, and that `Awake()` did not run before `Update()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts could be, based on his description of the problem - it sounded like it was a syntax error to me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah, you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me (granted with my limited exposure to unity) like you need to declare your variables at a global level. Try doing something like this:

```
// declare these variables in the global scope.
var x;
var y;
var z;

function Awake () {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetTouch) {
        x = x-1;
    }
    Transform.position = Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everything here worked out after I fixed that mistake. I couldn't use commas though, because apparently, Unity didn't have that.